# Companion Inventory Glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm about 60 hours in now, and have been using the same companion for the majority of the time.

I really would like to keep using this companion, but lately she's been getting... glitchy.

It started out that it wouldn't let me unequip her "default armors" -- the two or three that she started with. OK, I could live with THAT.

Over time, she started making mistakes with allowing me to take duplicates of an armor type that she had equipped at that moment, which she then took to calling her "default". I still couldn't take her original armor from her, even with new "default armor".

Now, she has like over 10 different types of armor that she is calling her "default armor". It won't let me unequip any of them at ALL. It gives the same error message, which is exactly as follows....

"You can't take your teammate's starting armor." -- for like 10 different types of armor, stacked and unstacked.

I would really like to keep this companion, but I just feel like she's kind of broken in my game at this point lol ... Is there a way to fix this? If not, should I/can I replace her? OR is this the sign of something much deeper and worse (game-breaking).

I am playing Xbox 360, which I know severely limits my options for fixing, but please let me know, as I have scoured the internet searching for answers to no avail...

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing on PC, you can try to install a follower overhaul, such as [Ultimate Follower Overhaul](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14037/) (UFO) or [Amazing Follower Tweaks](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/15524/?) (AFT). These should allow you to remove your follower's equipment.

It sounds to me though that your save is glitching out, something that often happens to very old, very long saves. In that case, and IF using the follower mods doesn't work (please don't try them at the same time) then you can use the save cleaner to try and clean up the game scripts on your save.

As with everything, make sure to **back up your game** before messing around, especially when it's in a delicate state.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same glitch on the ps3, the only fix I know is that if you marry her she will open a shop and you can buy off the bound armour from her shop.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to pickpocket a follower's default armor (it was unequipped at the time) after dismissing them, you should try doing that.